# in org-mode, how to demote all headers in a region?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In my org-mode file, I have a bunch of level 1 headings. I want to highlight some of them and demote them by one level to level 2. How do I do this? When I highlight the region and do <kbd>M-S-right</kbd>, I get `This command is active only in special context like tables, headlines or items`.

Comment: `M-<right>` is perfectly working for me!!

Comment: The method I use (because I've also had issues with `M-right`) is to collapse to to the level I'm indenting, do `F3` `M-right` `F4`, then `F4` for each headline to indent.  In other words, use a keyboard macro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use `M-right` rather than `M-S-right`.

Comment: Sometimes that works, sometimes it doesn't. It depends on the way I highlight it. If there are non-heading lines at the beginning of the highlighted region, then M-right just unhighlights the region. If I begin highlighting before the first heading, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here, at least, a sort-of workaround solution: use regexp-replace to change "^**" into "*". That should do the job, even if not in a pure Org way.